# How are $P(N_1=2, N_4-N_1=4)$ and $P(N_1=2, N_3=4)$ equivalent in a Poisson process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

> $$P(N_1=2, N_4=6)  = P(N_1=2, N_4-N_1=4) = P(N_1=2, N_3=4) = P(N_1=2) \cdot P(N_3=4)$$

What I understand is:

1. $P(N_1=2, N_4=6)$ means "the probability of count of 2 items arriving at step-1, AND 6 items arriving at step-4.
2. $P(N_1=2, N_4-N_1=4)$ means that "the probability of  count of 2 items arriving at step-1 AND the 4 items as the difference of steps 4 and 1.
3. which is same as $P(N_1=2, N_3=4)$ i.e. "the probability of count of 2 items at step-1 AND 4 items at step-3".

I understand (2), as (1) is represented as a "difference" term in (2).

I also understand that the increments of a Poisson Process are independent. Therefore, $$P(N_1 = 2, N_4-N_1=4)= P(N_1=2)P(N_4-N_1=4).$$

But, how are $P(N_1=2, N_4-N_1=4)$ and $P(N_1=2, N_3=4)$ equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that actually $P(N_1=2, N_4-N_1=4) \color{red}{\ne}P(N_1=2, N_3=4)$. In fact, we have $$P(N_1=2, N_3=4) = P(N_1=2)P(N_2=2),$$
while
$$ P(N_1 = 2, N_4-N_1=4) =P(N_1=2)P(N_3=4).$$

These are equal if and only if $P(N_2=2)=P(N_3=4)$, i.e. the rate $\lambda$ satisfies $$e^{-2\lambda}\frac{4\lambda^2}{2!}=e^{-3\lambda}\frac{81\lambda^4}{4!}.$$

This is the case  if and only if $e^{\lambda} = \frac{81}{48}\lambda^2$. As [this plot](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+e%5Elambda+%3D+%2881+lambda%5E2%29%2F48) shows, there is no $\lambda >0$ that satisfies this.

---

A correct simplification is as follows. Note that the increments of a Poisson process are independent. So $N_1$ and $N_4-N_1$ are independent. Therefore,
$$P(N_1 = 2, N_4-N_1=4)= P(N_1=2)P(N_4-N_1=4).$$
Also, by **stationary increments** of a Poisson process, $N_4-N_1$ has the same distribution as $N_3$. (In general, $N_t-N_s$ has the same distribution as $N_{t-s}$ for any $0\le s \le t$). Hence 
$$P(N_4-N_1=4)= P(N_3=4).$$

Combine these facts together to get $$P(N_1 = 2, N_4-N_1=4) =P(N_1=2)P(N_3=4).$$

Comment: Stationary increment say that :$P(N_{t+s} − N_s = k) = P(N_t = k)$.